# custom UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Is it real to make such UICollectionViewLayout in UICollectionView? Please, give me some ideas, how can i do this?
[image]

Comment: You need to try this yourself first, we can't write your code for you.

Comment: Ok. I thought that this problem has already been solved in web. Thanks

Comment: It probably has, but we can't be the ones to go searching for it. Search for your problem, find the code, reconstruct it to your needs, then post a new question when the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iCarousel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel), a third-party custom control for this purpose.

Check the following tutorials:

1. [iCarousel iOS](http://www.chupamobile.com/ios-frameworks-libraries/icarousel-303)
2. [How to Use iCarousel view controller in iOS](http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/how-to-use-icarousel-view-controller-in-ios/)